# ZK Listbox - OnClickListener -> SelectedIndex

Tags: listbox, onclicklistener, zk

Is it possible to implement an OnClick listener in a list box in ZK? The trigger when clicking on an item works fine with the following code, but I can't get to the clicked item (getSelectedItems () shows the items selected by checkbox or the topmost selected item, but I want to trigger something independent of it by clicking on it). That's why the OnSelect listener doesn't matter to me either, the checkbox element must be selected directly and is not automatically selected by clicking on the item.
Thanks for any hint.

ZUL:

```
<row>                            
    <listbox id="article_output" width="100%" height="" 
      multiple="true" checkmark="true" nonselectableTags="*">
     <listhead>
          <listheader label="Article"/> 
     </listhead>  
     </listbox>  
</row>
```

Create Model and Listener

```
public void fillListBoxWithArticles(final Listbox lb, List<Article> articles) {
    lb.setItemRenderer(new ArticleItemRenderer());
    lb.setCheckmark(true);
    lb.setMultiple(true);
    ListModelList<Article> lml_articles = new ListModelList<Article>(articles);
    lml_articles.setMultiple(true);
    lb.setModel(lml_articles);
    lb.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception { 
            logger.debug("SELECTED INDEX: " + lb.getSelectedIndex());
            setArticleToInfobox(articles.get(lb.getSelectedIndex()));
        }});
   lb.focus();
}
```

ItemRenderer:

```
public class ArticleItemRenderer implements ListitemRenderer<Article> {
@Override
public void render(Listitem item, Article data, int index) throws Exception {

    item.appendChild(new Listcell(data.getArticletitle())); }}
```

Comment: just move your eventlistener to your renderer.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes you overlook the obvious.